# Cache control max-age with aws s3 on deployment process

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, cache-control

I'm working with django and nginx, statics files hosted on aws s3 with a cloudfront service.

When doing web development at some point you have to face the page speed analyse from google.

And the standard "error to fix" showing is about setting an expiration time to your statics.

Recently, with BucketExplorer I was able to set a cache-control: max-age.
Then I had to invalidate all my staticfiles and re validate them.

It works great, even if it seems that google hasn't removed the warning yet.

But my question is, when I will upload new css / js or if someone on the blog add a new article with pictures etc, **how am I suppose to set a max-age to those new static files?**

- Do have I to repeat manually the process?
- Is there a proper way to automate it?

I tried it from my nginx, adding those lines:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {

expires 1M;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
expires 1y;
add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

but apparently s3 (or at least my network console) showed nothing, like ignoring those rules.

Comment: How would S3 know about your Nginx configuration?

Comment: Isn't it managing the header? As its write "add_header"?
But well, whatever, the question isn't really about nginx.